# Slideshow Jquery separado por categoria

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso de uma ideia de como fazer um slideshow separado por categoria, quero mostrar ao usuário um link para uma determinada categoria, ao clicar no link de mostrar um slideshow desta categoria, se clicar em  um segundo link de outra categoria, mostrar um slideshow referente à segunda categoria e assim por diante.

Comment: Vc pode utilizar o `carousel` do bootstrap para isso http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: se for na mesma página talvez tenha que usar ajax

Answer (score -2):

boa noite.

Não entendi tua duvida.

Tu ja tens as categorias e quer apenas um slide show para exibilas no click do mouse, ou tu queres saber como trazer as categorias do banco e exibi-las separadamente?

Qual o cms que vc utiliza?